# Cast exception while using zxing lib for QR scanner jim.h.common.android.zxinglib

Tags: android, zxing

I am using this code start QR code scanner using zxing lib

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(SummaryTab.this.getActivity(), R.layout.capture,R.id.viewfinder_view, R.id.preview_view, true);
```

The code compiles successfully, but while executing, it raises an exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bitss.abc/jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView cannot be cast to jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.view.ViewfinderView
```

Pardon my ignorance, I am new to andriod development. Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post more of your code?

Comment: The jim.h... library is based on the com.google ZXing lib.  I suspect you have import statements in your code that reference the class from the other library. In fact, given that this compiles, you probably have the jars from both libraries in your project.